# Unable to post attachment(with an image) to facebook page via python's Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api

My django website requires regular posting to the website's fb page. I am able to post content to the fb page(as an attachment) via a custom app. using python's facebook graph api.

However, when I try to post an attachment alongwith an image, the image does not appear.

Here is the code(except image I can see everything on the fb page):

```
....
import facebook
# our fb app. can post to fb page via "FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_FB_APP" token
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(settings.FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_FB_APP)
attachment = {}
message = ''
# don't know why it's not working!
attachment['media'] = [ {"type": "image", "src": {{FILE_URL}}, "href": {{page_url}}} ]
attachment['name'] = {{obj.title}}
attachment['description'] = {{obj.small_desc}}
attachment['link'] = {{page_url}}
attachment['caption'] = {{site}}
graph.put_wall_post(message, attachment, settings.FACEBOOK_PAGE)
```

#### What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You using `media` while you should use `picture` instead.

And you doesn't need to provide anything except the url of an image.

```
attachment['picture'] = {{FILE_URL}}
```

Comment: Using `attachment['picture'] = {{file_url}}`, displays a compressed image with a max. width of 90px. 
However, I want to **post images just like we share photos on fb (alongwith a message)**

Comment: Oh, just corrected (`picture` is the right one, image is something I've typed `wrongly`). And sadly you cannot specify dimensions of image anymore...

Comment: Actually, I always create a unique image(automated), and I want to post these images(using graph api) just the way we share photos on the wall. But the above code does not do that!